# Declaring a temporary variable into a global variable in javascript responseText

Tags: javascript, variables

I am trying to make xhr.responseText into a variable and then alert it but for a strange reason i cannot do so.

```
test2 = ""
function process(){
    url = "http://www.example.com/example.html"
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4){
        test2 = xhr.responseText
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
process();
alert(test2);
```

Thanks to anyone who can help on this issue.

Comment: `alert(test2)` can run before `onreadystatechange` as the latter is asynchronous, do your work in the handler or use a synchronous request..

Comment: Hey Alex K. can you provide me an example of how i'd set xhr.responseText as a global variable? Much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you're alerting before the test2 variable is filled with content (because of the XMLHTTPRequest needing some additional time to complete)

```
var test2 = "";

function process(callback){
    url = "http://www.example.com/example.html"
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4)
        {        
            test2 = xhr.responseText;
            callback();
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}

process(callbackFunction);

function callbackFunction()
{
    alert(test2);
}
```

Comment: I need to store it as a global variable because i need to use it in a later part of my script.

Comment: that's exactly what the code is doing... you just can't access the contents untill the xhr.onreadystatechange has been called since it's asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

You are firing an asynchronus request. The `alert` will be fired immediately after the process function is executed. Later when the response comes back, `onreadystatechange` is fired. If you plan to do anything with the result of your AJAX query, you should do it in the `onreadystatechange`. Like this...

```
 test2 = ""
function process(){
    url = "http://www.example.com/example.html"
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4){
        test2 = xhr.responseText
        alert(test2);
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
process();
```

Comment: So there is absolutely no way to make the result a global variable? I need to store it for another part of the script.

Comment: You can, but then you should execute the "another part" in the `onreadystatechange` function because that's when you'll have the responseText.

Comment: @Tom the result is still being stored in the global variable, only that it will be available only after you receive a response.

Comment: What will happen if i change true to false? It will first finish before going to another part of code?

Comment: Yes that fixed it, i just changed true to false.

Comment: @Tom - yes you got it there. That is an 'async' flag. Setting it to false will make the operation synchronous, which means no other code will run unless this is complete, effectively locking the browser if it is a long running process. Use it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous calls is generally not a good practice.
Maybe jQuery is something you could use?

Example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.example.com/example.html",
  success: function(data) {
    // now you can do something with the data
    alert(data);
  }
});
```